# How to combine multiple commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have the following commands.

```
cd import
zcat urls1.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p urls
cd /var/www/project1/
nano 1.php
```

As of now I'm executing it one by one.

Is there a way to combine those commands in one line?

Comment: Did you do any research for this question?

Comment: That was not my question. It is just that half a minute of googling  would have given you the answer. Hence, I was wondering what you had already found, if anything.

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted your question? I will neglect your anger. As a side-note, the question *"which one is better: using `;` or `&&` to execute multiple commands in one line"* is a lot better, has more research and would likely have attracted a great many upvotes.

Comment: There is a more generic variant of this question available at http://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-bash. It deal with exactly the question I mention in the previous comment.

Comment: Don't worry Giri. The essence of the question is interesting. I took the effort of making a generic variant of it.

Comment: @Private Good Work mate.. And yes I agree that your question is very clear than my question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, separate with a semi-colon like so:

```
dir; ls -l
```

Most lanugauges/shells use the semi-colon to signify the end of a command and to start new while evaluating from left to right.

Or as @RobieBasak recommends, use && instead of ; to guard against coding accidents.

```
dir && ls -l
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use `&&` instead of `;`. This ensures that subsequent commands are only executed if previous commands have not failed. This avoids some awkward consequences. For example: `cd /somewhere_else; rm -Rf *` could do something disastrous if `/somewhere_else` doesn't exist or you mis-spell it; `cd /somewhere_else && rm -Rf *` protects you from this.

Comment: The '&&' solution is so good, it should be the first recommendation in this answer. Please edit your answer and promote the better answer to first place.

Answer (score 10):

This illustrates more:

1. A ; B  – Run A and then B, regardless of the success or failure of A
2. A && B  – Run B only if A succeeded
3. A || B  – Run B only if A failed

source :https://www.howtogeek.com/269509/how-to-run-two-or-more-terminal-commands-at-once-in-linux/